# Conditionally toggle `preventDefault` on form submissions in Elm

Tags: elm

Is there a way to conditionally toggle `preventDefault` on form submissions?
I've tried using `onWithOptions`, below, but it seems only the first setting is used, even though I can see it change using `Debug.log`, when there is a name on the model.

```
, onWithOptions
    "submit"
    (if model.name == "" then
        (Debug.log "prevent" { preventDefault = True, stopPropagation = True })
      else
        (Debug.log "allow" { preventDefault = False, stopPropagation = False })
    )
    (Json.succeed FormSubmit)
```

### Updated with findings from answer

As stated by @Tosh, hiding the button resolves the issue:

```
, button
    [ onPreventClickHtml FormSubmit
    , Html.Attributes.hidden (model.name == "" |> not) ]
    [ text " prevent" ]
, button
    [ onClick FormSubmit
    , Html.Attributes.hidden (model.name == "") ]
    [ text "allow" ]
```

Where `onPreventClickHtml` is:

```
onPreventClickHtml : Msg -> Attribute Msg
onPreventClickHtml msg =
    onWithOptions
        "click"
        { preventDefault = True, stopPropagation = True }
        (Json.succeed msg)
```

Conditionally displaying the button ***does not*** work:

```
, (if model.name == "" then
    button
        [ onPreventClickHtml FormSubmit ]
        [ text " prevent" ]
  else
    button
        [ type' "submit", onClick FormSubmit ]
        [ text "allow" ]
  )
```

I'm using elm-mdl and so found implementing the solution more challenging because from my experience creating a custom *onclick* requires types which are not exposed by elm-mdl, and so need to be duplicated.

```
, if model.name == "" then
    Material.Options.nop
  else
    Material.Options.css "visibility" "hidden"
, onPreventClick FormSubmit

, if model.name == "" then
    Material.Options.css "visibility" "hidden"
  else
    Material.Options.nop
, Button.onClick FormSubmit



onPreventClick : Msg -> Property Msg
onPreventClick message =
    Material.Options.set
        (\options -> { options | onClick = Just (onPreventClickHtml message) })

-- Duplicated from elm-mdl
type alias Property m =
    Material.Options.Property (Config m) m

-- Duplicated from elm-mdl
type alias Config m =
    { ripple : Bool
    , onClick : Maybe (Attribute m)
    , disabled : Bool
    , type' : Maybe String
    }
```

Another approach, which worked for my scenario, was changing the button type:

```
, if model.name == "" then
    Button.type' "reset"
  else
    Button.type' "submit"
```

Comment: I reproduced it.  The event handler does not seem to get updated (`makeEventHandler()` in js gets called only once).  It may be a bug.  I suggest you to file an issue unless someone can give us an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple workaround suggestion until someone can show us how to solve it.

How about create two buttons (with different options as you've shown) and depending on the condition show only one of them?
You can use `Html.Attributes.hide` for that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Conditionally including the button runs into the same problem but hiding the button does work. I'm using elm-mdl, material design, and it's a bit ugly because it doesn't expose types which are seemingly needed to create a custom onClick, but I can get it to work. The direction I went was changing the button type, which worked from my scenario. I'll update my answer with some code snippets.